# JS: множественная загрузка картинок и превью

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, файлы, multiple

Нужно организрвать загрузку картинок в альбом и предусмотреть их превью.
Вот простая форма, тут всё просто:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="photos" name="photos[]" multiple accept="image/*">
</form>
```

И скрипт, который обрабатывает добавление фотографий:

```
$('input#photos').change(function () {

    var input = this;
    var photoList = $('div.photo-list');
    photoList.html();

    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        var file = input.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            photoList.append(...);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

Тут проблем нет, всё обрабатывается.
Но когда я хочу добавить ещё картинок, то старые затираются. Получается, что этот `input` забывает про старые файлы и затирает их новыми. Так ли это?

И если так, то как организовать добавление файлов? Вести отдельный массив и в него добавлять новые загружаемые файлы? И при отправке формы соответственно этим массивом заполнить `input`?

Comment: Попробуйте проверять существует ли файл.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-pure-javascript

Comment: @Jengas так конечно на сервере файлов еще нет. Я говорю о процессе до отправки формы.

Comment: Да, вы правы, нужно сохранять файлы в отдельный массив.